# Unload data from Store procedure in shell

Tags: shell, informix

I trying to unload data from a store procedure in informix  in a shell, but an error appear when i execute a shell scripting.

My Shell file

```
FILE="customer_report" 
PATH="/home/usrrep/DIR_1/DIR_2/" 
EXT=".txt"


dbaccess dataBase <<eof

unload to $PATH$FILE$1$EXT delimiter ','
execute procedure database:customerReports();
eof

echo Serial Number,Name,Office,Status,Product,Date,Phone1,Phone2,Email,Final Reult> $PATH$FILE$1.csv
cat $PATH$FILE$1$EXT >> $PATH$FILE$1.csv
exit 0
```

Whe execute a query the shell works fine, but when i try to execute a Store procedure throws next error:

```
809: SQL Syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 2
Near character position 0
```

The error is very explicit but i haven't idea what happening

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in `$1`?  What do you see when you run the shell script using `sh -x` (or your chosen alternative shell)?  Does the DB-Access script (the UNLOAD statement) work OK outside the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

unload to ... execute procedure ... doesn't seems to exist unless undocumented. 
One possibility is to use in customerReports()

```
select ... from ...into temp mytemptable
```

and

```
unload to ... select * from mytemptable
```

in the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

you could try with from table(). somelike like this:

```
> create procedure p2(c1 int) returning int,char(10)
 return 1,'aaa' with resume;
 return 2,'bbb' with resume;
 end procedure;

Routine created.

> execute procedure p2(1);


(expression) (expression)

           1 aaa
           2 bbb

2 row(s) retrieved.

> unload to x.unl select * from table(p2(1));

2 row(s) unloaded.

> !cat x.unl
1|aaa|
2|bbb|
>
```